# How to simulate change trigger manually, not with $(object).change(); or $(object).bind('change') or $(object).trigger('change')

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange

I would like to simulate change trigger. I want to trigger my change code on the end. I would like to change all my inputs that aren't disabled.

```
$('selector').load().each(function () {
    if ((typeof $(this).attr("VALUE") != 'undefined') && ($(this).attr("disabled") != 'disabled')) {
        //do something ...
        //then I want to simulate Trigger with something like that:
        $(this).val(0);
        $(this).val(tmp);
        //here i want code, that will triger my code on the end 

    }
    $("selector").bind('change', function () {
        // alert("change");
        CF_change($(this), "CF", clientCulture);
        SaveData($(this).attr('id'), $(this).attr('str_id'), $(this).val(), 0, '');
    });
}
```

Comment: Why did you exclude all the official ways to trigger the event handlers bound to an element ?

Comment: I think that @nataly means that he (she?) want's to trigger the event from code, not by the user.

Comment: This makes absolutely no sense. Changing the value with val() does not trigger the event, the only way to trigger the event handler is by actually changing something or using one of the methods that the OP doesn't want to use, so the answer is simple, it's impossible if you can't use any of the methods for programatically triggering an event.

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger the event by:

```
$("your_selector").change();
```

Comment: +1 because, even though you fail the reading comprehension test, you have at least given the correct answer.

Comment: It's hard to understand what OP was writing about, the I took it that he wants to trigger manually the event from code. I have some experience with non-english speaking people who try to describe something in English and I thought that this is what the problem is about ;) We'll find out when @nataly clarifies his question ;)

Comment: Well, yes, I agree. The reading comprehension failure is that the OP specified he didn't want to use `.change()` in the question title!

Comment: Sorry about my bad english, but Kamil T  you are right. I just want simulate the situation, when you go to input, change the value and triggered the change event. thanks in advence.